# Parse a String in C++ and connect input-arguments to existing variables

Tags: c++

I want to read an input string and connect their values to variables in my class.

Some example Inputs might be:

```
78 C 15.48
3 B
87 P 15
0
..
```

The first argument is an int from 0-100, second a char and third int or float. A String can consist of one, two or three arguments which are separated by space. After reading a line, this program does some calculations and then expects another input until a 0 is entered or a break occurred.

To read an input String, i'm currently using

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

My program already has the variables

```
int firstArgument;
char secondArgument;
float thirdFloatArgument;
int thirdIntArgument;
```

now, lets say `str` is: `46 C 87.3`
after reading the line my variables should be:

```
firstArgument = 46;
secondArgument = 'C';
thirdFloatArgument = 87.3;
```

How can I extract the Information from the input String?
I was thinking about counting the spaces to see how much values are given and then separating the string via this delimiter,as the amount of arguments might vary. So:

```
int count = 0;
int length = str.length();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    int c = str[i];
    if(isspace(c)){
        count++;
    }
}
```

with space count being 2 I now know that 3 arguments were passed, but I don't know how to go on from there. Using std:istringstream might be an option but from what I've seen online it is mostly used in a while loop to print each word of a string in a new line or like that. But my input can vary in the amount of arguments so a loop would not work.

I think I need something like: "String before first ' ' is `firstArgument`, String between first and second ' ' is `secondArgument`, string after second ' ' is either thirdFloatArgument or thirdIntArgument (respectively if only one or two arguments are given, which can be determined with the amount of spaces). But how would I do this? Or are there some easier approaches?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Read a line (`std::getline`) into a string (`std::string`). Put the string into an input string stream (`std::istringstream`) and get the first first value (using the plain `>>` stream extraction operator). If it's not zero, get the next value (the operator). If it's a floating-point operator get the floating-point value, if it's an integer operator read the integer value, otherwise do processing and go to next line.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I go the the next value? So I would do ```std::istringstream iss(str)``` and int p = 1; (not sure what it does), followed by iss > p; and I would be able to get the first argument.

Comment: Good, after that you have the first "argument" (like `78`, `3`, `87` or `0` , from your example input) in the variable `p`.  If the second and third "argument" depend on this number, you can now know how many more values you need to read: Zero, one or two. If the type of the third "argument" depend on this number as well, then you know if you need to read an integer or a floating point value last. It's a simple case of `if` or `switch` on the first integer value you know have in `p`.

Comment: Do all this in a loop, like `while (std::getline(std::cin, str))`.

Comment: Unfortunately, those values do not really depend on each other (at least most do not).  So I do not know how much more arguments will come.
I just realized one can use
```iss >> p;
firstArgument = p;
iss >> p;
secondArgument = p;
... ```
At least in theory. However, for the second 'step in', I do expect a char. and with:
```secondArgument = char(p);``` the output of secondArgument is 0. I would use my space counter and depending on the amount of arguments I might choose how deep to dig in. How would this look in a while loop?

Comment: `if (iss >> secondArgument) { /* Have the second argument */ } else { /* Doesn't have any second argument */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Some programmer dude mentioned it is a good idea to use `std::istringstream` to convert values from string to other data types. It allows you to treat input string the same way as you treat `std::cin`. Here is a code snippet that you can use in your case:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

struct Arguments {
    int first{};
    char second{};
    double third{};
};

Arguments parseArgs(const std::string& inputLine) {
    Arguments args;
    const int argc = std::ranges::count(inputLine, ' ');
    std::istringstream stream(inputLine);
    if (argc >= 0) {
        stream >> args.first;
    }
    if (argc >= 1) {
        stream >> args.second;
    }
    if (argc >= 2) {
        stream >> args.third;
    }
    return args;
}

int main() {
    std::string inputLine{};
    std::getline(std::cin, inputLine);
    const auto args = parseArgs(inputLine);
    std::cout << args.first << ", " << args.second << ", " << args.third << "\n";
}
```

Note that you have to compile this example using C++20 because I used `std::ranges`. If you do not have compiler that supports this standard you can use `std::count(inputLine.cbegin(), inputLine.cend(), ' ');`